# Why Facebook graph api not returning some of likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get my friends likes using Facebook graph api, but for some reason it's not returning some likes.  My friend have 95 likes but I can get only 81 ...

I'm using iOS sdk

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

   FBRequest *likesReq = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes?limit=100", friendID]];
   [likesReq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

      if (result) {
         NSArray *fbLikes = [result valueForKey:@"data"];
         NSLog(@"Likes count %d", fbLikes.count);

      }


   }];
}
```

**Likes count 81** instead of 95

Comment: SHow some code please!

Comment: The remaining likes might have some privacy associated with them. This is normal with Facebook to return less data because of privacy reasons.

Comment: @Ibrahim if there are privacy reasons why I see likes in user page? I think if I can see likes API will return tham...